# Comment first instance of string after specifc string

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I want to be able to comment only the first occurrence of `cin >> n;` after `int main`.

Doing this through bash, I've tried a combination of using grep and sed, but I'm new to bash and I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int n;
  cin >> n;

  cout << factorial(n) << endl;
  if (n > 10)
  {
    cin >> n;  // don't want it to change this one!
    double d = log(n);
    cout << d;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `sed` and a range-expression `0,/regex/s/regex/replacement/` which has the effect of putting `sed` at the end of it range when the replacement is made limiting the replacement to the first occurrence, e.g.

```
sed '0,/cin >> n/s/cin >> n/\/\/ cin >> n/' file
```

Result:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int n;
  // cin >> n;

  cout << factorial(n) << endl;
  if (n > 10)
  {
    cin >> n;  // don't want it to change this one!
    double d = log(n);
    cout << d;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If you have code before `main` that can include `cin >> n`, then you can use `int main` as the start of the range, e.g.

```
sed '/int main/,/cin >> n/s/cin >> n/\/\/ cin >> n/' file
```

Thanks to [@BenjaminW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w)

If you don't like the `\/\/` look, you can choose an alternative delimiter that will cut down on the picket-fence look, e.g.

```
sed '/int main/,/cin >> n/s|cin >> n|// cin >> n|' file
```

Comment: I think it should be `/int main/` instead of `0` ("first occurrence after `int main`, not first occurrence overall), and the comment indicator is probably `//` and not `#`.

Comment: That's a good thought. Let me toy with that. It is the use of `0` itself that has the effect of placing `sed` at the end of the it's range, I'll check if `int main` will work as well and update.

Comment: The only issue with the range between two regexp is this: Suppose that for some reason the text `cin >> n` appears on the same line as `main`. In that case, the range will extend up to the **second** occurrence of `cin >> n`. (That's what 0 is good for - it avoids exactly that problem.) In this case, it's probably safe to assume this won't happen, but for a more general case it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: You could reduce the duplicate occurrences of `cin >> n` from 3 to 2 with `s|cin >> n|// &|`. 2 duplicates still isn't great but it's a common side-effect of using range-expressions (which is why I advocate never using them and using a flag instead) and it's better than 3 :-).

Comment: Ooh. Good thoughts both mathguy and Ed. This was one where `sed` provided a solution but didn't seem to provide the "perfect" solution. There are a lot of caveats to covert in a short solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/int main/{f=1} f && sub(/cin >> n/,"// &"){f=0} 1' file
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int n;
  // cin >> n;

  cout << factorial(n) << endl;
  if (n > 10)
  {
    cin >> n;  // don't want it to change this one!
    double d = log(n);
    cout << d;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `awk` solution seems a bit more flexible in addressing `main()` on same line that would cause `sed` issues.

Comment: It also doesn't require any duplicate conditions which is why I prefer it.